# format string '%g' requires an argument of type 'double', but variadic argument 1 has type 'long'

Tags: c

I got the warning (not error) as written in the heading for code like this:

```
printf("value=%g\n", 5L);
```

I understand it is not an error, but why a warning?
Why can or can't we use `long` in place of `double` despite `long` storing much more information?

Comment: What is not clear???...The warining is telling you all you need....and take a look at [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: From where you are getting this?

Comment: Can you add more details. eg - your code

Comment: There's no guarantee that a `long` is the same size as a `double`, in fact Visual C++ uses 32-bit `long` even on 64-bit systems and `double` is typically 64 bits. Also, integers and floating point values are stored differently in memory, their bit-patterns are not the same. Lastly, mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: _despite 'long' stores much more information_..............What?.....o_O

Comment: `long` does not store "much more information".  At best, if both `long` and `double` are 64-bit, they store pretty much the **same** amount of information, with `double` giving up accuracy for range.  If `double` is 64-bit and `long` is just 32 bits, however, `double` will store about 2^32 **times** the amount of information as `long`.  In that case, `double` has both much more accuracy **and** range than `long` does.

Answer (score 5):

"`long` stores much more information" is simply incorrect. If `long` is 32-bit (which I believe it is on Windows/MSVC), it stores far less information, and if it's 64-bit, it stores the same amount of information, since `double` is 64-bit, but uses/interprets that information in a different way (as sign/exponent/mantissa).

However this is largely aside from the point. C does not define the behavior if the actual argument types to `printf` mismatch the format specifiers, and in practice mismatching them will not produce reasonable/meaningful results. Don't do it. Either use the right format specifier matching the type you have, or cast to the type you want it formatted as (being aware that the cast may lose information).

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's not strictly a warning is because `printf` is a variadic function where the types of all arguments after the first are not specified.

Because `printf` is a known function with well defined semantics, the compiler can do additional optional checks of the arguments against the format string.  The compiler is not required to perform these checks hence it generates a warning instead of an error.

Also, there are cases where you can "get away" with a mismatch if two types have the same size and representation, for example `long` and `long long` on systems where both are 8 bytes in size.

That being said, parameters must match the format specifier.  Failing to do so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This is mainly because the variadic nature of the `printf` function means that its arguments can't be implicitly converted from one type to another.

As an example, take an x64 Linux system where both `double` and `long` are 8 bytes.  The way these two types represent values is very different so the value that might be printed would not be what you expect.  Also, in this environment integer values are typically passed to functions on the stack while floating point values are passed via floating point registers, so if you pass a `double` when the function is expecting a `long` or vice versa it won't even be reading in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

`long` is used for storing a whole number, while `double` is used for storing a floating-point number. In memory, they're stored as ones and zeros but in different ways. When you use `%g` for the wrong type, your program will try to read it from the memory in the wrong way. That will result in an incorrect output.